# Java name Objects with a variable name

Tags: java, minecraft

so I am making a plugin for Minecraft. Its basically a team plugin. What I need to do, is be able to create multiple teams, but I cant seem to figure out how to change the object name to the players chosen team name. Here is what I mean:

```
if (l.equalsIgnoreCase("NewTeam")) {
    teamName= args[0]; // This is the players chosen team name
     Team newTeam = new Team(teamName, sender);
     newTeam.addPlayer(sender);
```

Since this is a server plugin, it will have to deal with multiple teams, which would mean it is creating lots of team objects, but all with the object name newTeam. Does anyone know of a better way that I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: why does it matter?  you may share the same variable name, but I assume each object will be created with a unique teamName so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I thought they would interfere, will they not?

Comment: it depends entirely the scope of the variable, which from this small snippet is not clear

Comment: what you want to change in the above code.?

Comment: Also look into arrays (`Team[]`) and HashMaps (`Map<String, Team>`) if you want several teams visible from the same scope.

Comment: There is no such thing like an "object name". newTeam is a variable name (of a variable local to the block, in this case), and the variable holds a reference to the Team object.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for a mapping of team names to team objects?
Then, you may do it as follows:

```
Map<String,Team> teams = new TreeMap<String,Team>();

//Returns the team for 'teamName' or creates one, if it doesn't exist
public Team getTeam(String teamName)
{
    Team team = teams.get(teamName);
    if(team == null)
    {
        team = new Team(teamName,sender); //is 'sender' specific for a team??
        teams.put(teamName,team);
    }
    return team;
}
```

Comment: HashMap beats TreeMap in terms of speed; why choose a TreeMap?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak : I didn't consider speed issues. With a tree map implementation, teams are all in a pretty order for listing. I Agree, a HashMap should be preferred if possible.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Maps, how would I access each Team object to preform functions. For example, I need to be able to do, Red.addPlayer, blue.addPlayer, etc.

Comment: @user1947236 `teams.get(name).addPlayer(player)`

Comment: @JanDvorak What happens if "name" is not the name of any team?

Comment: @user1947236 `get` returns `null` (I think, look up the documentation for `Map#get`) if the corresponding key is not in the map. If you call a function of null, you get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the Bukkit API, and further that this is being done inside a CommandExecutor's onCommand method, so here's what this should likely look like:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){
   if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("newteam")){ //Make sure this is the right command
      if(args.length == 0) //If the sender hasn't included a name...
         sender.sendMessage("You need to include a team name!"); //Tell them they need to
      else{ //Otherwise...
         Team newTeam = new Team(args[0]); //Create a new team with the designated name
         if(sender instanceof Player) //If the sender is a player (could be console)...
            newTeam.addPlayer((Player) sender); //Add them to the team
         /*
          * Insert some code to save/store the newly created team here
          */
      }
      return true; //Return (for Bukkit's benefit)
   }
}
```